# How to setup simplesli.de?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm totally new to jQuery and desperately need help setting up a simple text slideshow.

I like the look of [simplesli.de](http://www.simplesli.de/) but have no idea how to get it working. There are NO instructions of what to put in your HTML and where to put it! Yes there are snippets of code on the site for different types of slideshow, but when I copy and paste the code for the text presentation into my page, all I get is static content.

I've downloaded the js file and placed it into a js folder and linked to this from my page - still nothing working. I really don't understand what to do here. How do I get it working? how do I style it? What am I missing?

----EDIT---
Ok this is the code I have in my HTML file:

In the `<head></head>` I have the following:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../_js/jquery.simpleSlide.js"></script>`

I downloaded the jquery.simpleSlide.js file and put it into the _js folder that is in the root directory of my sire. The page I'm working on is situated within a sub-directory of the site hence the '../' in the link.

I've then taken an example code for one of the sliders from the site and placed this within my HTML where I want it to appear. This is now:

```
<div>
    <div class="simpleSlide-window" rel="1">
     <div class="simpleSlide-tray" rel="1">
       <div class="simpleSlide-slide" rel="1" alt="1"> content for slide one </div>
       <div class="simpleSlide-slide" rel="1" alt="2"> content for slide two </div>
       <div class="simpleSlide-slide" rel="1" alt="3"> content for slide three </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I test this I get get three lines of static text on the page. Nothing is working at all. I don't have any sort of slideshow, no buttons, no interactivity - just static boring old content. What am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell I've done what the site is instructing me to do.

I've tried adding this to my head...

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
simpleSlide({
    'status_width': 20,             // Integer. Sets the width of the status slideshow's window element.
    'status_color_inside': '#000',  // String. Sets color of status window element.
    'status_color_outside': '#FFF', // String. Sets color of status tray element.
    'set_speed': 500,               // Integer. Sets speed of all animations. Represented in milliseconds.
    'fullscreen' : 'false',         // String. 'true' sets slide window for full screen. For obvious reasons, cannot work with more than one simpleSlide window per page.
    'swipe' : 'false',              // String. 'true' turns on swipe functionality for touch devices.
    'callback': 'function()'        // String. Sets callback to actuate after simpleSlide initial config.
});
```

but that makes no difference either.

I could really do with some help here as I'm totally baffled. If the site actually posted clear instructions of how to implement this I wouldn't be here asking for help.

----ANOTHER EDIT---
Where is the CSS??

Comment: How did you link to it from your page? It's hard to fix a problem without knowing anything about it. Anyway, the slideshow provides rather detailed instructions, and you would just put the HTML wherever it is you want the slideshow to appear...

Comment: where are the detailed instructions that you mention as I can't find them...

Answer (score 0):

Trouble is, you're running the setup code before the DOM elements exist. You probably just need to delay the JS code until the DOM is ready:

```
$(function() {
    simpleSlide();
});
```

Also, make sure you're loading the jQuery library; I don't see that anywhere in your sample.

**UPDATE**

Working example [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/4zrJE/3/).

Comment: As I said earlier I'm new to jQuery - so I have no idea what you mean - could you explain further. Also where does it tell you to load the jquery library - where do I get this? How do I load it?

Comment: SimpleSli.de is a jQuery plug-in. You need jQuery, the core library, before it will work. http://www.jquery.com

Comment: so do I download it and shove it in my js directory or do I link to it?

Comment: Whichever. There's a CDN available from jQuery, Google, and others. I updated my answer with a working example. As easy as the author claims the plug-in to be, it's really not. You have to dig for examples and there weren't many.

Comment: Cory - thank you so much! I would never have worked all of that out. I've been using firebug to try and eek out the bits I need as I've not found them on the site. That's given me plenty to get on with - just got to work on styling it and then trying to figure out how to make it auto-play - hmm that should be fun - not! thanks so much for your help! I need to sit down over the holidays and do the learn jquery in 30 days course - it's hard at the moment as I've got an 8month old and he takes up all my time!

Comment: I'd love to get the arrows working just like they do on the website - don't suppose anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the auto-slider to work? Trying to implement...
    <div class="auto-slider" rel="group"></div>

// Add this javascript, and ensure it appears after the simpleSlide() call

$('.auto-slider').each( function() {
    var related_group = $(this).attr('rel');

    window.setInterval("simpleSlideAction('.right-button', " + related_group + ");", 4000);
});

and it's not working!

Comment: Another question - sorry to be annoying - is there a way to set this so that the width is 100% i.e. it's flexible with the size of the browser or device window? I've currently got it set to 240px so that it looks ok on a mobile device, but once you see it on an iPad or desktop, it looks really daft.

Comment: @user1178434: Your last few comments should be new questions.